# Remove recent Adobe XD project from XD Start Screen?

Tags: adobe-xd

Is it possible to remove Recent projects from Adobe XD home Screen? Most of my clients aren't familiar with XD and I have to walkthrough the project from my laptop. I don't want them peaking on other projects I'm working on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that there's a way to remove specific projects from the recents.

It seems that you can probably clear *all* of them - though not sure this is so helpful... https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests/suggestions/36494119-bring-the-clear-recents-menu-item-back

[image]

As a solution, I would just store the actual XD files inside a folder with all your other client related docs, you can open the file directly from that folder without needing to first open XD.